# Allowed collections in meteor app with auth branch

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to update a collection in my meteor app and am getting the following error:

update failed: 403 -- Access denied. Can't replace document in restricted collection.

In the server I have the following code:

```
    Songs = new Meteor.Collection("songs");
    PlayLists = new Meteor.Collection('playlists');
    PlayChannels = new Meteor.Collection('playchannels');

    Meteor.publish('songs', function () {
      return Songs.find();
    });
    Meteor.publish('playlists', function () {
      return PlayLists.find();
    });
    Meteor.publish('playchannels', function () {
      return PlayChannels.find();
    });

    Meteor.startup(function () {
      Songs.allow({
        insert: function () { return true; },
        update: function () { return true; },
        remove: function () { return true; },
        fetch: function () { return true; }
      });
      PlayChannels.allow({
        insert: function () { return true; },
        update: function () { return true; },
        remove: function () { return true; },
        fetch: function () { return true; }
      });
      PlayLists.allow({
        insert: function () { return true; },
        update: function () { return true; },
        remove: function () { return true; },
        fetch: function () { return true; }
      });  
    });
```

And I'm making the call as follows:

```
    PlayChannels.update({_id: Session.get('playchannel')},{current:Session.get('current')});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am also facing same issue here. How did you dealt with it BTW?

Comment: Same here... have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

What was wrong was the call. The correct way to do it is:

```
PlayChannels.update({
    _id: Session.get('playchannel')
}, {
    $set: {
        current: Session.get('current')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

the fetch option of allow should return an array, not a boolean, or just remove it completely. I think this should solve it, because in the same scenario I had allow fail because fetch was returning a boolean, thus not taking in the allowance for update.

```
Songs.allow({
        insert: function () { return true; },
        update: function () { return true; },
        remove: function () { return true; } 
      });
```